# Defining a class method with parameter by using initialize

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, methods

I am a newbie to ruby. I wrote the following code for a problem.  I believe this code is correct.

```
class Array 
  def sum
    result = 0
    self.each do |x|
      result += x
    end
    result
  end
end
```

What I want to know is how to write the exact code without using the `.self` method inside the `sum` method. Here is what I am trying to do...I know the following code is incorrect but it'll show you what I am trying to get at.

```
class Array
  def initialize
    @array = []
  end

  def sum (@array)
    result = 0
    @array.each do |x|
      result += x
    end
    result
  end
end
```

So what I am trying to do is get this code to work by passing an argument in the `sum` method and NOT using the `.self` method.  Any help?  Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do it that way?  Using self is the preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

How is the below?

```
class Array
  def sum
    inject(0,:+)
  end
end
[2,9].sum # => 11
```

---

without self:(not a good code,rather use the above one)

```
class Array
  def sum
    result = 0
    each do |x|
        result += x
    end
    result
  end
end
[1,1].sum # => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, if you don't use self, then self is implied. I'll use your code as an example.

In your code, you type `self.each`. If you simply wrote `each` it would also work. A snippet of your code would look like this:

```
def sum
  result = 0
  each do |x|
    result += x
  end
  result
end
```

That would work the same exact way.

```
[1,2,3,4].sum
#=> 10
```

Why? In this case `[1,2,3,4]` is `self`, and because `each`, a method,  isn't being called on anything, then `self` is implied and your code is interpreted as if you said `self.each`. Note, that in this case like many, you would want to type `self.each`, because it makes a lot more sense to the reader. Hence, the way you wrote it on top would be best.

If I was you, I would now explore `inject`. You could do what your method does by calling the inject method:

```
[1,2,3,4].inject { |accum, elem| accum + elem }
#=> 10
```

Even better,

```
[1,2,3,4].inject(:+)
#=> 10
```

I'll leave it to you to explore the depths of Ruby, this very interesting method, and how `inject(:+)` works. Note: when reading on the internet, `:inject` and `:reduce` are the same. Just like `:count` and `:length` for an array. *I put* `:` *in front of them as a hint in regards to* `inject(:+)`.

Answer (score 1):

> So what I am trying to do is get this code to work by passing an argument in the sum method and NOT using the .self method. Any help?

I believe you are really confused. There are at least two kind of methods (that I want you to focus on):

- Instance methods
- Free methods (methods defined within the `Kernel` class)

In your case what you really want is a free method (unchained from the `Array` class) that can be defined like this:

```
def sum(array)
    array.reduce(:+)
end
```

and used like:

```
sum([1, 2, 3])
# => 6
```

What I'd suggest to you, is to stick with the instance method version instead:

```
class Array
    def sum
        reduce(:+)
    end
end
```

And use it like:

```
[1, 2, 3].sum
# => 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have to argue that you actually want to use self rather than exclude it.  As far as I'm aware, using self within instance methods is the preferred practice.  As for your sum method, I would probably write it like this:

```
class Array
  def sum
    total = 0.0
    self.each {|x| total += x if ["Fixnum", "Float"].include?(x.class.name)}
    total%1==0 ? total.to_i : total
  end
end

a = [1, 2, 3, "y"]
b = [2, "z", 4.3]

puts a.sum #=> 6
puts b.sum #=> 6.3
```

Comment: Just a note, sum isn't a class method. It's an instance method. (Not trying to be pedantic, just don't want the asker to be confused).

Comment: I see you actually only sum the fixnums and floats. I would argue that it might be better for the method to not let the user be so loose in terms of what is in the array. It's cool to be able to sum just the numbers, but you might want another method for that. I could be wrong though.